# How to find 1st and 2nd smallest number out of 3 variables C#

Tags: c#

```
decimal angle1 = decimal.Parse(angle1_textbox.Text);
decimal angle2 = decimal.Parse(angle2_textbox.Text);
decimal angle3 = decimal.Parse(angle3_textbox.Text);
```

How to find the smallest 2 numbers from this?

Comment: How would you do it by hand? It's something similar with a computer. Create two variables, `biggest` and `secondBiggest`second Biggest. Set them both to a very small number. Loop over the 3 angles. If a number is bigger than `biggest`, set `secondBiggest` to the value of `biggest` and `biggest` to that number.

Comment: `var smallest = new[] { angle1, angle2, angle3 }.OrderBy(x => x).Take(2).ToArray()`

Comment: Find the bigger value. The other two left are the smallest.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest form would be

```
var min1 = Math.Min(angle1, angle2);
var min2 = Math.Min(Math.Max(angle1, angle2), angle3);
var tuple = Tuple.Create(Math.Min(min1, min2), Math.Max(min1, min2));
```

So the first element of tuple is the smallest, the second is second smallest.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the smallest number is to iterate through all the numbers and compare each to the current smallest number found. If it's smaller, replace the current smallest with that number and continue. The placeholder number therefore must be initialized with the *largest* possible value so it's immediately replaced by the first value in the array.

For example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    decimal angle1 = decimal.Parse("1");
    decimal angle2 = decimal.Parse("2");
    decimal angle3 = decimal.Parse("3");
    
    // Put the numbers into an array so we can loop over them
    decimal[] numbers = {angle1, angle2, angle3};
    
    // To start, set our two placeholders to the largest possible values
    decimal smallest = decimal.MaxValue;
    decimal secondSmallest = decimal.MaxValue;
    
    // Loop through our set of numbers and replace the 
    // placeholders when a smaller number is encountered
    foreach(decimal number in numbers)
    {
        if (number < smallest)
        {
            secondSmallest = smallest;
            smallest = number;
        }
        else if (number < secondSmallest)
        {
            secondSmallest = number;
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"smallest: {smallest}");
    Console.WriteLine($"second smallest: {secondSmallest}");
}
```